# Преобразование str в int с пустыми ячейками pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Минимум': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
               'vendor1': ['', '', '65000', '', '14000', '11000', ''], 
               'vendor2': ['22000', '12000', '', '', '15000', '', '71000'], 
               'vendor3': ['', '', '', '', '', '9900', ''], 
               'vendor4': ['23000', '', '', '', '13600', '', '76000']})
```

Имеется DataFrame df, который имеет типы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Задача состоит в том, что бы в каждой строке от vendor1 до vendor4 включительно найти минимальное значение и вставить его в первый столбец 'Минимум'. Что бы в итоге первый столбец состоял из значений: 22000, 12000, 65000, 0, 13600, 9900, 71000.
И сюда логично напрашивается код:

```
df['Минимум'] = df.loc[:,'vendor1':'vendor4'].min(axis=1)
```

Но я не могу совладать с типами столбцов и ячеек, т.к. знаний не хватает. Понимаю, что сейчас строки в df не могут иметь параметра минимум и поэтому код не работает, но если все переделать в int то программа ругается на пустые ячейки. Если начать использовать fillna(0).dtype(int) то код фактически работает, но нули мешают. В общем я устал и запутался.

Вопрос.

Подскажите, как в нужных в столбцах (от vendor1 до vendor4) преобразовать типы данных (в int) только заполненных ячеек, и при этом игнорировать пустые ячейки? Ну и в дальнейшем что бы минимальное значение выбиралось из нужного диапазона только в том случае, если ячейка заполнена цифрой.

Иными словами нужно, что бы получилось так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно привести в числовому типу с коррекцией ошибок:

```
df["Минимум"] = df.loc[:,'vendor1':'vendor4'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').astype('Int64').min(axis=1).fillna(0)
```

```
   Минимум vendor1 vendor2 vendor3 vendor4
0  22000.0           22000           23000
1  12000.0           12000                
2  65000.0   65000                        
3      0.0                                
4  13600.0   14000   15000           13600
5   9900.0   11000            9900        
6  71000.0           71000           76000
```

Либо, as per @CrazyElf, можно явно сохранить тип int:

```
df["Минимум"] = df.loc[:,'vendor1':'vendor4'].apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').astype('Int64').min(axis=1, numeric_only=True).fillna(0)
```

````
   Минимум vendor1 vendor2 vendor3 vendor4
0    22000           22000           23000
1    12000           12000                
2    65000   65000                        
3        0                                
4    13600   14000   15000           13600
5     9900   11000            9900        
6    71000           71000           76000
​```
````

Comment: Спасибо. Тоже отличный вариант!

Comment: У вас всё-равно обратно в `float64` эта колонка превращается после `min`, это видно прям по результату. Но если добавить в `min` параметр `numeric_only=True`, то `Int64` сохранится )

Comment: @CrazyElf ну она и изначально-то в int не превращалась  - nan не давал ;)

Comment: @strawdog Так `Int64` как-раз умеет в `NA` )  Но вот `min` почему-то этого не понимает по дефолту )

Comment: int - умеет. но pandas делает же неявное преобразование в float, если есть nan. Так что, min по умолчанию все верно делает.

Comment: @strawdog Но `Int64` - это тип, **в котором есть `NA`**. Его специально для этого добавили. Это не тоже самое, что старый тип `int64` с маленькой буквы.

Comment: @CrazyElf, да, верно. туплю

Answer (score 3):

Для преобразования `''` в `NaN` используем способ `mask(df == '')`, другие способы есть [тут](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pandas/pandas-replace-blank-values-with-nan/).
Для преобразования строковых значений в числа используется [pandas.Int64Dtype](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Int64Dtype.html).
Второй строкой, меняем `NaN` на 0 и конвертируем в целое.

```py
df['Минимум'] = df.loc[:, 'vendor1':'vendor4'].mask(df == '').astype(pd.Int64Dtype()).min(axis=1)
df['Минимум'] = df['Минимум'].fillna(0).astype(int)
df
Out[6]: 
   Минимум vendor1 vendor2 vendor3 vendor4
0    22000           22000           23000
1    12000           12000                
2    65000   65000                        
3        0                                
4    13600   14000   15000           13600
5     9900   11000            9900        
6    71000           71000           76000
```

Comment: В догонку: более компактное определение среза по колонкам `df.iloc[:, 1:]`.

Comment: Мы уверены, что до после vendor4 нет других, ненужных колонок?

Comment: Спасибо огромное. У меня заработало. А то всю голову сломал. 
@strawdog в проекте, где будет такой код, справа столбцы еще будут, но думаю, с этим проблем не будет возникать. Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: @torsaf насчет столбцов справа - это я к комментарию @Ensay про `df.iloc[:, 1:]` - тут у вас будут обрабатываться _все_ столбцы после 0-го